# How do I pass a substitution value from a webhook payload for Cloud Build?

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, yaml, webhooks, google-cloud-build

The Google Cloud Build - Webhook Trigger documentation shows the proper URL to POST to invoke the build trigger. However the documentation does not describe how to pass a value from a webhook JSON payload to a substitution variable.
Can we pass substitution variables in the POST body?
This is my JSON body :

```
{

  "substitutions": {

    "projectId": "ABC",

    "repoName": "XYZ"

  }

}
```

This is my inline YAML build file for Cloud Build :

```
steps:
  - name: maven
    args:
      - '-c'
      - >-
        echo "SUB1:${_SUB_ONE} SUB2:${_SUB_TWO} PROJECT_ID:$PROJECT_ID
        REPO_NAME:$REPO_NAME"
    entrypoint: bash
substitutions:
  _SUB_ONE: '${body.substitutions.projectId}'
  _SUB_TWO: '${body.substitutions.repoName}'
```

`${_SUB_ONE}` and `${_SUB_TWO}` does not populate the values "ABC" and "XYZ" respectively in the echo statement.

Output of the echo statement:

```
SUB1: SUB2: PROJECT_ID:dev REPO_NAME:itemdetails
```

Comment: Can you share how you invoke Cloud Build? Which URL are you calling?

Comment: Using a Webhook URL, https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectId}/triggers/CloudBuild:webhook?key={key}&secret={secret}.
Not adding values of {projectId} ,{key} and {secret} due to security concerns

Comment: And  you use a POST with your JSON body in example, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: It should work... Can you try to replace the simple quote by double quote? `_SUB_ONE: "${body.substitutions.projectId}"`. And (or) try to add the dynamic substitutions option `options:
    dynamic_substitutions: true`

Comment: "${body.substitutions.projectId}" gets auto formatted to '${body.substitutions.projectId}' on saving the inline YAML.

Getting this error now : **[_SUB_TWO -> ${body.substitutions.projectId}]: bad substitution, [_SUB_ONE -> ${body.substitutions.repoName}]: bad substitution**

Comment: Still does not work I guess? Can you try to set the ${body} in a substitution variable and to print it?

Comment: ${body} does not populate anything, here is the output :
```SUB1: SUB2: PROJECT_ID:dev```
Both SUB1 and SUB2 has ${body} set into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to use $(body) instead of ${body}. For ex :`$(body.substitutions.projectId)`